# Websocket rails (Faye-websocket) handshake error code 200 - AWS ElasticBeanstalk, nginx, puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get a websockets enabled app working, but I'm running into an error when trying to connect:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://[domain.com]/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

I'm following the tutorial here (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets) which uses the gem faye-websocket. It works fine locally (with puma), but when I try to deploy it to AWS ElasticBeanstalk that's running nginx + puma the websocket request can't connect.

I'm creating a new WebSocket connection with the following javascript (with my own domain):

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://[domain.com]/");
```

Following the tutorial, I created a middleware class that checks incoming requests for websocket, and handles it accordingly. On my local server, the request environment hash looks like this:

> "rack.errors"=>#>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"text/plain", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"2.11.1", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2", "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "REQUEST_PATH"=>"/", "REQUEST_URI"=>"/", "HTTP_VERSION"=>"HTTP/1.1", "HTTP_HOST"=>"localhost:3000", "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"Upgrade", "HTTP_PRAGMA"=>"no-cache", "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"=>"no-cache", "HTTP_UPGRADE"=>"websocket", "HTTP_ORIGIN"=>"http://localhost:3000", "HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_VERSION"=>"13", "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36", "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip, deflate, sdch", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"en-US,en;q=0.8",

Whereas on AWS it looks like this :

> {"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.errors"=>#, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"text/plain", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"2.11.1", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"127.0.0.1", "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "REQUEST_PATH"=>"/", "REQUEST_URI"=>"/", "HTTP_VERSION"=>"HTTP/1.0", "HTTP_HOST"=>"[domain.com]", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"=>"194.80.196.162", "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"close", "HTTP_PRAGMA"=>"no-cache", "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"=>"no-cache", "HTTP_ORIGIN"=>"http://[domain.com]", "HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_VERSION"=>"13", "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36", "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip, deflate, sdch", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"en-US,en;q=0.8",

So I can see that on AWS, the request headers HTTP_CONNECTION and HTTP_UPGRADE aren't being switched over to websockets.

However, I've tried setting my nginx configuration but I can't figure out how it works (e.g. https://gist.github.com/KeithP/f8534c04d20c2b4e4b1d)

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websockets.conf" :
    content: |
      upstream backend {
          server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
      }

      server {
          listen 80;

          access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
          error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

          server_name env1.t3tiiauce6.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

          # prevents 502 bad gateway error
          large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

          location / {
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

              # prevents 502 bad gateway error
              proxy_buffers 8 32k;
              proxy_buffer_size 64k;

              proxy_pass http://backend;
              proxy_redirect off;

              location /assets {
                root /var/app/current/public;
              }

              # enables WS support
              location /cable {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
              }
          }
      }
```

From what I understand, this routes requests going towards /cable to the backend rails app and upgrades the connection to websockets. However when I try /cable I get a 404 error (as there is no matching route).

So how can I get my rails app handshaking with websockets correctly? Any help would be much appreciated!! I've also tried using the websocket-rails gem and got handshake error code 500

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to get it to work! In the end, the following file put in the .ebextensions folder got it going:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined in another file
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /websocket {
    proxy_pass http://my_app/websocket;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
  }

  location /assets {
    alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location /public {
    alias /var/app/current/public;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

And my Javascript changed to:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://[domain.com]/websocket");
```

Hope it helps anyone who comes across similar issues!